# Angular - auxiliary routes not working

Tags: angular

I need to load components into a router outlet nested within another component. In my program component (`ProgramComponent`, `app-program`) I have a router outlet

```
<a routerLink="admin1">One</a>
<a routerLink="admin2">One</a>
<router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>
```

In the route configuration I have:

```
{ path: "program", component: ProgramComponent, children: [
    { path: "admin1", component: AdminOneComponent, outlet: "admin" },
    { path: "admin2", component: AdminTwoComponent, outlet: "admin" }
]}
```

The child components for admin1 and admin2 don't load into the router outlet. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{admin:['admin1']}}]">
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{admin:['admin2']}}]">
```